# How to check light intensity using iPhone camera

Tags: iphone, ios

Is there any way to check the light intensity using iPhone? Does API allows to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[Obtaining Luminosity from an iOS Camera](https://www.transpire.com/insights/blog/obtaining-luminosity-ios-camera/)

Comment: i'm not so sure about that tutorial. yeah it lets you figure out the luminance of a picture but it ignores all the settings used to take the photo. the camera is actually doing a lot of work to take a photo with a balanced luminance (adjusting shutter, possibly aperture, ISO). you could have a long night exposure or a very brief day time exposure and get the same luminance value for it.

Comment: the original question asked about light intensity which to me would mean acting more like a light meter. so i'd think the answer should actually do more than just give a definition of a candela the proceded to ignore it completely.

Comment: The tutorial addresses this: "There is 1 problem, most iOS devices have cameras that auto adjust there brightness based on the amount of ambient brightness, this can tarnish results to make them slightly less accurate, however the adjustment is not enough to make the output from this kind of algorithm meaningless."

Comment: It acknowledges but then goes on to solve a totally different problem.

Comment: What happens when you're link doesn't work any more? You need to post a better answer

Comment: Getting this issue "No visible @interface for 'UIImage' declares the selector 'rgbaPixels' ". How to solve this ?

Comment: link broken, please check

Answer (score 5):

I suppose you can easily do this yourself:

1. take a still => `UIImage`.
2. convert the `UIImage` to a `CGImageRef` (`UIImage.CGImage`).
3. Now, read every pixel's color and perform such code: `x += (red + green + blue) / 3.f;`
4. Calculate the average brightness: `avg = x / numberOfPixels;`.

`avg` will now give you a float indicating the average brightness of the still. Most of the time (if not always), this will be identical to the light intensity.

Comment: One thing to be careful of is exposure mode (and perhaps other settings like white balance). Having looked quickly through the docs you can lock the exposure mode at it's current value but not sure what that really means in practice. What you really want is a RAW image without any processing so that you will get accurate values for processing. I'd also be careful about which format you get the image back in, if you get BGRA then you should also look at the alpha channel as well.