# iOS - Is there a way in ObjC to tell if a device is being used inside or outside?

Tags: ios, objective-c, environment-variables

I would like to adapt text colors to the local environment. Is there a way to tell if a device is being used outdoors or not? (preferably in ObjC).

Thanks

Comment: If the phone could know it was outside, how would that provide information about colors in the local environment?  Sounds like what we need is some kind of "color sensor" on the device.

Comment: It would be much, much easier to ask the user than just about anything else.

Comment: @danh I was thinking that if I could tell that the device was outside, I could use a color scheme and perhaps a font family that could be more visible. I believe that a lot of apps cannot be viewed well in daylight.

Comment: @NobodyNada  It would be easy for me to ask the user, but I want this to be easy for the user. To go to a setting each time they go inside and outside just isn't very "friendly".

Comment: If you want to adapt the display based on the brightness, then why do you care if the user is inside or outside? Think about outside at night versus inside in a bright room, etc.

Comment: See settings->display and brightness->auto-brightness.

Comment: @rmaddy If the display was based on light sensitivity, perhaps night light would result in either the same as indoors or a third set of color/fonts

Comment: Looks like you can use the camera and then adjust for the ambient light intensity: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6855717/how-to-check-light-intensity-using-iphone-camera

Comment: Thanks @Thunk. That looks like it could work. I'll look into it.

Comment: Looking into this... It seems you must take an image with the camera before you can find the image values (make sense). If this is correct, then is even more intrusive than @NobodyNada's solution. For now, I guess that's the way to go.. answer?